# How to prevent Gutenberg from resizing images in gallery upload?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

In posts, the Gutenberg editor will by default automatically resize via css any images uploaded as galleries, resulting in too small and blurry images.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent this from happening in the first place, or find a way to revert the image size back to full size - does anyone?

Whether there's an already built in option I'm missing, or if there's a plugin that fixes this, or ideas for how to change the code. Any ideas welcome!

ps. note that when uploading single images, the right hand side toolbar has an option to change the image sizes - however this does not appear when uploading multiple images at once via gallery mode.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Styles on Gutenberg can be added same like the classic editor through which you can add stylesheet and then target the element and manipulate styles.

- Add Theme Support `add_theme_support('editor-styles');`
- Add Stylesheet `add_editor_style( 'css/custom-editor-style.css' );`

If you want to change functionality or core block then it is recommended to create new block instead of manipulating core blocks because it can create layout or functional problems with other plugins.

- New blocks can be created with this guide of [Writing Your First Block Type](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/).
- Stylesheet of your blocks can be added by using this guide [Apply Styles From a Stylesheet](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/applying-styles-with-stylesheets/)

These action hooks can also be used:

- `enqueue_block_editor_assets` - for enqueuing data only on backend that is Gutenberg Editor.
- `enqueue_block_assets` - for enqueuing data on frontend + backend